# Installation Error while installing TeX Live 2020 on Windows 10

Tags: texlive-2020

While installing TeX Live, my system installed all 4032 packages. But in the end, the installation failed. **I have no antivirus installed in my system, but still getting this error.**

I downloaded the `.exe` file (`install-tl-windows.exe`) of 18 MB from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

[image: Screen shot of installation error!]

Comment: I need help, please suggest what to do next for installation ??

Answer (score 0):

It did not install all packages. Various occurrences of

```
Installing [40xx/4032], time/total ...
The system cannot find the path specified.
TLPDB::_install_data: Decompressing c:\....tar.gz failed for http://..
TLUtils::install_packages: failed to install ...
     ... will be retried later.
Retrying to install: ...
```

I suggest trying again. You may have picked a bad moment, while the download site was updating itself.

Otherwise, it might help to go into advanced mode and pick a smaller scheme, such as 'basic scheme'. You can always add the full scheme later.

There is also a command-line option -select-repository which provides a drop-down menu of available mirrors. Some mirrors might have a better connection than others.